# How to log from multiple processes with different context (spawn/fork)?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, queue, python-logging

I have a Python application that spawns multiple daemon processes. I need to create these processes [via the `spawn` start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods). Since I want to log into a single file, I follow the [official docs on multiprocessing logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes). Thus I have created a `multiprocessing.Queue` and a `logging.handlers.QueueHandler`, as described in the tutorial.

Now the problem is that since I use the `spawn` start method (under Linux), but the default start method (context) under Linux is `fork`, it seems this logging queue does not work correctly in my case. When I log from the spawned process, then nothing ever shows up in my log. However, to check my code I tried to log into the same queue from the main process, and then these log messages show up correctly.

So in other words: Using the queue from the main process works, but from a spawned process that same logging queue does not seem to work any more. Note that I tried both, using the `Queue` class directly from `multiprocessing`, as well as the one from `multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")`. Fun fact: when I directly `put()` something into the queue from the process, then it shows up in the logs. Just when I call the `logger.error()`, then nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you pass the `Queue` to the worker process? with spawn, you cannot inherit a global like you can with fork. You must explicitly pass the queue as an argument to the `Process`. If you tried the global approach, it would even appear to work as during import a new queue unrelated to the original would have been created, so you wouldn't get `NameError`, but the queue wouldn't be connected to the one in the main process.

Comment: have you tried [logger-tt](https://pypi.org/project/logger-tt)?

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you can't use a `Queue`, you should still be able to use a `SocketHandler` with a network receiver. There are other recipes in the cookbook - see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network) and especially [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#running-a-logging-socket-listener-in-production) - they have sample code you can adapt to your specific needs.